# Problem with plot of discontinuous function of 2 variables and adding legend to a contourplot

Tags: plotting

I have 2 problems with which I would need help: 
-first one is that I would like to plot a discontinuous function of 2 variables but can't succeed (see attachment) 
-then I also would like to display a legend with a contour plot on which there are several ellipses but can't figure out (also see attachment). I don't want the usual contourplot legend with color graduation but one like : 
blue->ellipse one 
red->ellipse two

```
    s1t = 90
    s2t = 40
    s1c = -130
    s2c = -60
    f[x_, y_] := (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 - x*y/(s1t)^2 /; x > 0 && y > 0 
    f[x_, y_] := (x/s1t)^2 + (y/Abs[s2c])^2 - x*y/(Abs[s1c])^2 /; 
x > 0 && y < 0
    f[x_, y_] := (x/Abs[s1c])^2 + (y/s2t)^2 - x*y/(s1t)^2 /; 
x < 0 && y > 0
    f[x_, y_] := (x/Abs[s1c])^2 + (y/Abs[s2c])^2 - x*y/(Abs[s1c])^2 /; 
x < 0 && y < 0
    ContourPlot[f == 1, {x, -30 Pi, 30 Pi}, {y, -45 Pi, 20 Pi}, 
Axes -> {True, True}]
    ContourPlot[{(x/s1t)^2 - x*y/(s1t*s2t) + (y/s2t)^2 == 
1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 + x*y*(1/(s1t^2) - 1/(s2t^2)) == 1, 
x^2/(s1t^2) + y^2/(s2t^2) - x*y/(s1t^2) == 1, 
x^2/(s1t*Abs[s1c]) + 
y^2/(s2t*Abs[s2c]) + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
 x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y + 
2*x*y*1/(2*s45^2)*(1 - (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c] + 1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*
    s45 - (1/(s1t*Abs[s1c]) + 1/(s2t*Abs[s2c]))*s45^2) == 1, 
x^2/Abs[(s1t*s1c)] +  y^2/Abs[(s2t*s2c)] + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
 x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y - 1/(2*Sqrt[s1t*s1c*s2t*s2c]) == 1, 
x^2/Abs[(s1t*s1c)] + 
y^2/Abs[(s2t*s2c)] + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
 x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y + 1/Sqrt[s1t*s1c*s2t*s2c] - 
1/(2*S^2) == 1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 == 
1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 - x*y/(s1t*s2t) == 
1, (x*y - x^2)/(s1t*s1c) - (y^2/(s2t*s2c)) + 
x*(s1t + s1c)/(s1t*s1c) + y*(s2c + s2t)/(s2t*s2c) == 
1, (1.95*x*y - x^2)/(s1t*s1c) - (y^2/(s2t*s2c)) + 
x*(s1c + s1t)/(s1t*s1c) + y*(s2c + s2t)/(s2t*s2c) == 
1}, {x, -165 Pi, 70 Pi}, {y, -75 Pi, 30 Pi}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
FrameLabel -> {sigma1, sigma2}, PlotLabel -> failure surface, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[f[x,y] == 1, {x, -30 Pi, 30 Pi}, {y, -45 Pi, 20 Pi}, Axes -> {True, True}]` ?

Comment: Your second ContourPlot is incomplete: what is s45?

Comment: Fracture mechanics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here: first, as cormullion pointed out in comments, you need the argument of the first `ContourPlot` to be `f[x,y]==1`, not just `f==1`. The reason is that the `x` and `y` in your function defition for `f` are just placeholders, that can substitute for whatever arguments are passed. *Mathematica* doesn't assume that the `x` you used in the function definition is the same as the `x` used in a plot range. So:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 1, {x, -30 Pi, 30 Pi}, {y, -45 Pi, 20 Pi}, 
 Axes -> {True, True}]
```

[image]

I'm not sure what you mean by it being discontinuous. It doesn't look discontinuous either in a `Plot3D` or in a `Plot` holding one variable constant. In fact if you look at the function, at the point that it switches definition, several terms converge to zero no matter which function is being used. So it is actually effectively continuous even if it it isn't continuously differentiable. (It would have helped to remove the `Abs[s1c]` complication for `s1c` and `s2c` and simply used positive variables instead. They don't appear outside `Abs` expressions.)

For your second plot, you need the `ContourStyle` option to style the contours, unsurprisingly enough. You also have several undefined variables, including `s45`, which I've set to be 50 in the following. There is also a capital `S`. Please be aware that it is not good practice to name variables with single capital letters as it might clash with a built-in function.

Having defined `s45`, the following works:

```
ContourPlot[{(x/s1t)^2 - x*y/(s1t*s2t) + (y/s2t)^2 == 
   1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 + x*y*(1/(s1t^2) - 1/(s2t^2)) == 1, 
  x^2/(s1t^2) + y^2/(s2t^2) - x*y/(s1t^2) == 1, 
  x^2/(s1t*Abs[s1c]) + 
    y^2/(s2t*Abs[s2c]) + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
     x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y + 
    2*x*y*1/(2*s45^2)*(1 - (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c] + 1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*
        s45 - (1/(s1t*Abs[s1c]) + 1/(s2t*Abs[s2c]))*s45^2) == 1, 
  x^2/Abs[(s1t*s1c)] + 
    y^2/Abs[(s2t*s2c)] + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
     x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y - 1/(2*Sqrt[s1t*s1c*s2t*s2c]) == 1, 
  x^2/Abs[(s1t*s1c)] + 
    y^2/Abs[(s2t*s2c)] + (1/s1t - 1/Abs[s1c])*
     x + (1/s2t - 1/Abs[s2c])*y + 1/Sqrt[s1t*s1c*s2t*s2c] - 
    1/(2*S^2) == 1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 == 
   1, (x/s1t)^2 + (y/s2t)^2 - x*y/(s1t*s2t) == 
   1, (x*y - x^2)/(s1t*s1c) - (y^2/(s2t*s2c)) + 
    x*(s1t + s1c)/(s1t*s1c) + y*(s2c + s2t)/(s2t*s2c) == 
   1, (1.95*x*y - x^2)/(s1t*s1c) - (y^2/(s2t*s2c)) + 
    x*(s1c + s1t)/(s1t*s1c) + y*(s2c + s2t)/(s2t*s2c) == 
   1}, {x, -165 Pi, 70 Pi}, {y, -75 Pi, 30 Pi}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
 FrameLabel -> {sigma1, sigma2}, PlotLabel -> "failure surface", 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

If you additionally provide a value for `S` (I used $2$ for the purposes of the next plot), you'll get more contours.

[image]

Adding a legend, if that's really what you meant, is quite straightforward in version 9: add the following option to the end of the contour plot and you get the following:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, 
 {"something", "something else"}], Bottom]
```

[image]

As a side note, the `PlotLabel` should be a string in quote marks. You only got away with it in this case because multiplying `failure` and `surface` results in `failure surface` in canonical (alphabetical) order.